# When using Google Payments for an in-app purchase, does the App admin see any information identifying or associated with your google account?

Tags: google-play-store

For example,

Let's say I have 2 play store accounts signed in on android:

> alice@gmail.com
>
> bob@gmail.com

Event 1:
I sign into the app using alice@g, and then make a payment in the app using the Google Play Payment Method (GPPM) associated with alice@g's account, and which is then assigned order: GPA.111...

Event 2:
I then delete the app's data in settings and remove then reinstall it on the same device, but sign into it using bob@g. I then make a payment in the app using the GPPM associated with alice@g (since it is available and already on the phone), which is assigned order: GPA.222...

My question is (under the assumption that the app is not given the unique device id) for Event 2, is there anyway for the App-admin to associate bob@g's login with the alice@g login (for example, does the GPPM send the app admin an e-mail address such as alice@g or an id, such as gppm-id-alice, or gppm-randomId-associated-with-alice) or is each payment with GPPM fully anonymous?

Answer (score 1):

It is not fully anonymous. [Google Payments Privacy Notice](https://payments.google.com/payments/apis-secure/get_legal_document?ldo=0&ldt=privacynotice&ldl=en-GB) under the "Information that we collect" section states that:

> For example, when you make a purchase or transaction using Google Payments, we make certain personal information about you available to the company or individual you purchase from or transact with. This includes sharing your personal information with the developer from whom you purchased when you use Google Payments to make a purchase on Google Play. When you add a third party form of payment to your Google Payments Account, we may exchange certain personal information about you, such as your name, profile image, email, IP and billing address, phone number, device info, location and Google Account activity info, with the third-party payment provider as necessary to provide the service.

Information about the account used for the payment is shared. If that information is an email address like in your example, the app's developer receives Alice's information not Bob's.